# runtime complexity Power(x.N)

Tags: time-complexity, computer-science

I'm trying to figure out the upper and lower boundaries of the next equation (runtime complaxity):

0 < c <1 , () = () + ((1 − )) + 1

What I do know is that if c<0.5 -> the part of the equation that matters is the right one, and if c>0.5 -> the part that matters is the left on.
How do I proceed?

Comment: since `0 < c <1` can `cn` have decimal value also or it lies in `1 < cn <n-1` with integer values only?

Comment: I'm not so sure it matters.
The point is that one side of the equation would take much longer to get down to it's minimal value- while the other side would be too short for us to care about. I am not sure what my approach to this question should be.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming-

```
0 < c <0.5 , () = ((1 − )) + 1
0.5 <= c <1 , () = () + 1
```

You can find upper and lower bounds as follows-

**For lower bound-**

We have to select value of `c` in such a way we get minimum value of `T(cn)` or `T((1-c)n)`.

Which can be simply checked to be at `c=0.5` as value of value of `T(cn)` or `T((1-c)n)` decreases as c approaches 0.5.

Therefore,

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + 1
//which implies
T(n) = T(n/(2^k)) + k
```

Now, let `n = 2^x`

Or, `x = log(n)` giving us

```
T(n) = T(1) +log(n)     //lower bound
```

**For upper bound -**

There can be two answers depending what values are permissible-

**1)**`cn` or `(1-c)n` can have *decimal values* in their function-

Now value of `c` can be selected in such a way that `cn` or `(1-c)n` aproach `n` by using `c` approaching `1` but slightly lower (eg- c = 0.9999999999) for `cn` and value approaching `0` for `(1-c)n`.

In such a case, the upper bound will be infinity as the function will keep on calculating `T(x)` where `x` approaches `n`.

**2)**`cn` or `(1-c)n` take floor value -

If you dont know what is floor value, it is truncated value of decimal number where decimal part is removed or in **coding terms** you *typecast* `float` to `integer`.

Now, `cn` or `(1-c)n` can have a maximum value of `n-1` as `c` cant be equal to `zero` or `one`.

Therefore,

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + 1
T(n-1) = T(n-2) + 1
```

and so on.

which gives,

```
T(n) = T(0) + n
```

Hence having a time complexity of O(n).

**3)**`cn` or `(1-c)n` take ceil value -

If you dont know what is ceil value,then in **coding terms**  you *typecast* `float` to `integer` and add `1` to it.

Now, for `c` approaching `1` and `0` in `cn` and `(1-c)n` respectively than their ceil value is `n`.

Therefore,

```
T(n) = T(n) + 1
```

which has infinity as its complexity.